# Python connected datagram socket

Tags: python, sockets, python-2.7, udp

I'm building a simple client-server multiplayer game and I want to have connected UDP sockets. However, when I call the `listen()` method it produces `Operation not supported` exception.

```py
try:
    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    server.bind((host, port))
    server.listen(5)
except socket.error, (value, message):
    print "E: " + message  # E: Operation not supported
```

Is there a way to have connected datagram sockets?

Answer (score 4):

UDP protocol is connectionless and thus you really cannot create connections between 2 sockets in the same manner as with the TCP client and server; thus you also cannot do the `listen` system call on an UDP socket, as it concerns only the TCP server sockets. Instead you use `socket.recvfrom` to receive datagrams from any address:

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind((host, port))
data, addr = sock.recvfrom(65536)  # this will fit the maximum datagram
```

You can respond to the client (if they still have a socket open), by destructuring the `addr` which is a `host, port` tuple for `socket.AF_INET`, `socket.SOCK_DGRAM`.

```
client_host, client_port = addr
```

You can send data back there with `sendto`

```
sock.sendto(data, (client_host, client_port))
```

If you want to use a well-known port, you will `bind` the socket; if not, the system will assign a port for you.

---

It is possible to do a `connect` system call with datagram sockets on many socket implementations; this serves as a sort of filter, that drops the packets coming from unwanted sources, and for setting the default outgoing address for `sock.send` (it is still OK to use `sock.sendto` on such socket to another address, though the response might be dropped because of the "connection"). This is very useable on a client or between 2 nodes if they agree to use 2 well known ports with each other.

However if you do `connect` on server, it cannot serve any other requests on this socket. Also, `listen` with its queues only relates to `SOCK_STREAM` sockets.

Thus in case of many clients to 1 server, you could have the server listen to socket `12345`, and when a client contacts the server, the server could respond from `server:12345` with a message that contains another port number that the client should use with the server.

Comment: I'm not sure if you are saying that datagram sockets can't be connected in python, or in general. AFAIK, even though not common, UDP sockets can still be connected. See section 2.1, for instance: http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/print/bgnet_A4.pdf
"Datagram sockets are sometimes called “connectionless sockets”. (Though they can be connect()'d if you really want)"

Comment: My question is how to implement the connected UDP sockets. Should I have the client trying to connect to a different range of known ports? If so, how should I tell the server to listen on such range? I use threading for multiple connections, so, in principle, no problem with not serving other requests.

Comment: So the correct way to connect on the server side would be to get the message ``msg, addr = s.recvfrom(32)``, eventually parse it, and perform a ``server.connect(addr)``?

Comment: Something like that. If there are more problems you should ask a new question